# Print geopoint object from parse.com

Tags: label, parse-platform, geopoints

I want to print on label my geopoint from parse.com.
using

```
 <label class="edit-location"><%= location %></label>
```

Show [object Object]

if i use

```
 <label class="edit-location"><%= JSON.stringify(location) %></label>
```

Show {"__type":"GeoPoint","latitude":40,"longitude":-30}

What the right format to show only, 40,-30 (using this example)

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<label class="edit-location"><%= location.latitude + "," + location.longitude %></label>
```